# convert byte array to hex in c#

Tags: c#, sql

I need to run a stored procedure from code. One of the input parameters is rowVersion of the table. rowVersion is a byte array ( {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 13, 191} that's 0x0000000000000DBF in db). So if to add rowVersion this way :

```
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@myPKRowversion", 0x0000000000000DBF);
```

my sp is working. But when I'm adding it like here:

```
uint a = 0x0000000000000DBF;
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@myPKRowversion", a);
```

or if I convert byte Array to string like:

```
string a = "0x0000000000000DBF";
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@myPKRowversion", a);
```

my sp is not working. 
What should I do to make my sp work?

Comment: Note that `uint` only represents 4 bytes, not 8.

Comment: Can't really test this, but 0x0000000000000DBF is detected by the IDE as being an Int32, not a UInt32. So your working example and your first non-working example aren't the same. Does it work if you use an int instead of a uint?

Comment: @Tim solution that JonSkeet suggested is working fine in my code. But anyway you are right also. When I changed uint to Int32 my sp does not give me error also!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I suggest you add it *as a byte array*. For example:

```
byte[] bytes = new byte[] { 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 13, 191 };
cmd.Parameters.Add("@myPKRowVersion", SqlDbType.Binary).Value = bytes;
```

If you're trying to specify bytes, the most natural type is a byte array...